# Why is my python function running differently when placed in a class

Tags: python, pandas, function, class

I am re-organizing and cleaning up my code and have moved a set of functions to work in a class. Basic set up is fine, as one the functions works fine, while the others do no. The code runs as expected while not in a class, so I am suspicious there is a slip up in my handling of `.self`.

I have read through the code over and over. Rewrote things in a different way to see if I messed something big up.

As a note I am using `pandas` dataFrames if they handle different in a `class`.

Example code below.

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

class clss(object):

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x1 = x  # x is a pandas data frame
        self.stat = defaultdict(dict)


    def worker0(self, key, key0):
        # Change value at given coordinates 
        if key in self.stat and key0 in self.stat[key]:
            self.stat[key][key0] += 1
        else: 
            self.stat[key] = dict(key0=0)

    def worker1(self, key, key0)
        if key in self.stat and key0 in self.stat[key]:
            self.stat[key][key0] += 2
        else: 
            self.stat[key] = dict(key0=0)

    def master(self):

        for a in self.x1.index:
            if self.x1.loc[a, 'val'] == 1:
                self.worker0(a, foo)
            else:
                self.worker1(a, foo)
                self.worker0(a, blah)

        self.x1 = DataFrame(stat).T
        print(self.x1)


x = read_csv('file.csv')  #index = [0, 1, 2] 
c = clss(x)
c.master()
```

Now depending on the contents of `x`, I should get an output like:

```
    foo     blah
0   4       1
1   10      4
2   1       30
```

Instead I get:

```
    foo     blah
0   15      35
1   15      35
2   15      35
```

As I have it the wrong way is the sum of all the properly divided values. However I am not completely sure if that is the case but it appears to be somewhat true.

To give more context, I have a `csv` with a list of events (`rows`) and each event has some amount people in each `column` . If an event is a specific event, change a correlated value in a `dict` for each person at the specific event.

Edited to improve example and provide context

Comment: The code you posted won't even run - `master()` refers to undefined variables `key`, `key0`, `key1`, and `stat`.  We need a [mcve] to be able to help you.

Comment: Edited code to be executable

Comment: instead of reading code over and over put many `print()` in code to see values in variables in different moments - this way you will see how values are changed. You can also print information which part of code is executed (`print("I'm in else")`). And it should helps you find problem.

Comment: if you put some example data (assigned to `x`) and expected result then we can run it and search problem.